# Shopify graphql get article by handle?

Tags: shopify, graphql

is there a way to get the handle of a shopify blog article ? I'm talking about a human readable id/handle. It seems that this exists on the liquid side, but not sure why it doesnt exist on the graphql side.

Definitely the article "url" field is human readable, so im thinking that it must be there somewhere

Answer (score 1):

(At the time of writing this in 2018, the Shopify GraphQL API was in beta.)

The documentation for blog articles does not look complete yet as it only shows the `id` field, and I would expect other fields such as `handle` and `body_html`.
https://help.shopify.com/api/graphql-admin-api/reference/object/onlinestorearticle

Using the [GraphiQL tool](https://help.shopify.com/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/graphql-explorer/graphiql) it looks like some filtering is supported, but I could not get a match using `handle`.

[image: screenshot from graphiql explorer]

(I would like to know how to use introspection to find the list of supported filter parameters...)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Shopify Developer Docs, it seems like that the GraphQL for Articles has not yet been implemented properly, altough the articles object does exist in the documentation. For the use of articles you have to stick to the use of the REST API.

See here: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-01/objects/OnlineStoreArticle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Despite being a pretty old question was looking for the answer to this yesterday.

Using the Shopify Storefront API I was able to do it using the following query:

```
query {
  articles(first: 1, query: "<handle>") {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        contentHtml
        handle
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try this I get "Field 'articles' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'". Any idea why?